# How to add event Listeners in Angular?

Tags: angular, events, addeventlistener

I am writing an app  using Angular 6, trying yo listen to plotly_click events (Visualization library). How can i set up a listener?

The Angular is recommending to use the `Renderer2` from API > @angular/core.
They are providing a `listen` function which is supposed to start an event listener. But any way this is not really working, i can to listen to events on `document | body` but not on specific DOM Element.
There's also the method `addEventListener()` from `EventManager` in API > @angular/platform-browser. But i am facing the same problem.

```
import {... , Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { EventManager } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-abc',
    template: '<div id="myDiv">abcdefghjk</div>',
})

@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
   this.renderer.listen(this.myDiv, 'click', (event) => console.log("Trying to listen to click event on that DIV"));
    // Or i tried also to use the evenetManager method
   this.eventManager.addEventListener(this.button, 'click', (event) => console.log("Trying to listen to click event on that DIV"));
}
```

This what i get as an error (I got the same error when using event Manager):

```
SummaryComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined
    at SummaryComponent.push../src/app/summary/summary.component.ts.SummaryComponent.ngOnInit (summary.component.ts:21)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:10105)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:11371)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:11333)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11970)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11930)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SummaryComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11922)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11315)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11556)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should register the listener after the view was initialized and not in the `onInit()` method.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.renderer.listen(this.myDiv, 'click', (event) => console.log("Trying to listen to click event on that DIV"));
}
```

Comment: This is correct way to add event listeners in Angular as fromEvent or addEventListener won't work with events set up by Angular's EventManager - e.g. Hammer events from HammerModule. TY

Answer (score 2):

Another option is RxJS [fromEvent](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html) creation operator

```
fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'wheel')  // here you can use any DOM element
   .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),  // don`t forget to cleanup!  
       throttleTime(150),    
       tap((e: WheelEvent)=> this.doFancyStuff(e.deltaY))
   ).subscribe()
```